# Facebook Work History Unavailable

Tags: c#, facebook, history

I am relatively new to FB development, but I have managed to do what I wanted, which was to get a list of friends, and from each of them, get their work history. I accomplished this by using Facebook's own C# SDK, and using the Get method on each of my friends, basically doing: _fa.Get("/").

This worked perfectly up until a couple of days ago, where it suddenly stopped working, and now I no longer have the work history (and education for that matter) available to me in the JSONObject which is returned from the Get method. One other thing of note is that a couple of my friends who installed the app I am developing (as a means of testing), do return their work history, but other friends (who have not installed the app), and do have a work history open (which I can see if I look at their profile by browsing into it with my browser) do not return it in my Get call...

The obvious explanation is that FB changed something, and now applications can no longer access this information unless installed on a specific user profile (hence the odd behavior).

Has anyone else encountered the same thing? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the answer appears obvious and is probably some change in default privacy settings that have been rolled out. Note that Facebook has introduced a couple of new features this week, most notably the "places" stuff. Most likely work history is not shared anymore by default. You probably only had access because the work history was publicly visible anyway.

**Update**

Seems to me, the best places to check for changes is the [developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and the [developer roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your comment - I have looked into the FB Blog and other sources, but can't find any mention of this change - how common is this type of change? I mean, how easily do apps break when FB does something like this unannounced?